# Where to get a specific version of Castle.Core

Tags: castle-windsor

I've got a dll I'm trying to register that has a reference to Castle.Core.dll 3.0.0.0.  However, I can't find this specific version.  The closest I've found (for .net 4) is 3.0.0.2227.  I've checked the Castle Project official site, and their project on Sourceforge...

The exact message I get:

`RegAsm : error RA0000 : Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=3.
0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Castle Project doesn't include the TeamCity build number in the assembly version, only the file version, this is to avoid breaking the strong name on each build. The build you've found is very likely the one you want.

Version 3.0.0 binaries were released on sourceforge before we moved to using GitHub releases.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/Core/3.0/

This is an extract of what you'll see in our build scripts:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("$(AssemblyVersion_Major).$(AssemblyVersion_Minor).$(AssemblyVersion_Build).0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("$(Project_Major).$(Project_Minor).$(Project_Build).$(Build_Revision)")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("$(Project_Major).$(Project_Minor).$(Project_Build)$(BuildName)")]
```

https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/buildscripts/Castle.Common.Targets#L200